# Mysql 5.7.13 innodb unique column varchar(500)

Tags: mysql, innodb, unique-constraint, unique-index

I need to maintain a unique index on a `varchar(500)` column of a table of my Mysql 5.7.13 database.

The charset is set to UTF8 so, as far as I know, the limit in characters is 255 since I am using innodb engine. 
I know also that exists the option `innodb_large_prefix` that should extend the dimension up to 3072 bytes. I tried to configure my db to support this feature, but it does not work. I tried to insert two identical 500 characters long rows with the last character different, but I get a unique constraint error since, as I assume, the uniqueness check is performed on the first 255 characters.

Am I missing something? Have I misunderstood the purpose of this option?

P.S I enabled the `innodb_file_format = Barracuda` as pointed in mysql documentation.

Thanks for the help.
Simone

Comment: What is your table's row format? It says in the doc it's only for dynamic or compressed row formats, so it might be that.

Comment: @rlanvin I changed the row format to ´DYNAMIC´ first and `COMPACT` then, but the result is the same. The unique constraint is computed on the first 255 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

It turned out that the innodb engine were configured fine. 
The problem is that I created the table before enabling the `innodb_large_prefix` option, setting the unique index on the `varchar(500)`.

After deleting and re-creating the index on the `varchar(500)` field, the unique constraint start to work as expected.